# Problem on converting xml string structure to XDocument object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have xml string which I want to convert to XDocument object. I've been following this example from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2.

The problem is instead of getting this below result as in the example

```
    <!-- comment at the root level -->  
<Root>  
  <Child>Content</Child>  
</Root>
```

I got the below result

```
 {<!-- comment at the root level -->
<Root>
<Child>Content</Child>
</Root>}
BaseUri: ""
Declaration: {<?xml version="1.0"?>}
Document: {<!-- comment at the root level -->
<Root>
<Child>Content</Child>
</Root>}
DocumentType: null
FirstNode: {<!-- comment at the root level -->}
LastNode: {<Root>
<Child>Content</Child>
</Root>}
NextNode: null
NodeType: Document
Parent: null
PreviousNode: null
Root: {<Root>
<Child>Content</Child>
</Root>}
```

I want to get clear xml result without other metadata like nodes information as shown below

```
<!-- comment at the root level -->  
    <Root>  
      <Child>Content</Child>  
    </Root>
```

i'm using XDocument.Parse() method

I have added the code I'm using

xmlString declaration

```
var xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?><!-- comment at the root level --><Root><Child>Content</Child></Root>";
```

and this is how I create XDocument object

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Below is the xmlString declaration var xmlString = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?><!-- comment at the root level --><Root><Child>Content</Child></Root>";                    and this is how I create XDocument object XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

Comment: The MSDN example works as expected: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p8ZtfY. Without posting any code we cannot tell what could happen wrong.

Comment: i have modify my question by adding codes. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given example from MSDN delivers the expected output of

```
    <!-- comment at the root level -->  
<Root>  
  <Child>Content</Child>  
</Root>
```

The output you posted looks like all the properties of the `XDocument`. The `XDocument` object contains more information than just the plain XML you parsed.
In the example the output that is produced by the line `Console.WriteLine(doc);` is the string you gave in as the XML because it calls `doc.ToString()` which produces the "raw" XML output.

So I think you may got confused with the `XDocument` containing more information (properties than your raw xml). But you can perfectly query your XML data using LinqToXML(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview).

It looks like the parsing works exactly as it should (parsing raw XML to a object of type XDocument).